# Converting function from Oracle PL/SQL to MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, t-sql, database-migration

I have several Oracle functions that are similar to the one below. I don't know much about Oracle and although I have made in roads on a major query re-write.  I'd like to ask for some help on how to convert this function to SQL Server 2008.

I have tried using the online conversion tool at `www.sqlines.com` and benefited from many pages there...  but not successful in converting this function....

Thanks in advance, John

Oracle source:

```
function OfficeIDMainPhoneID(p_ID t_OfficeID)
return t_OfficePhoneID
is
    wPhID  t_OfficePhoneID;
    wPhID1 t_OfficePhoneID;
    cursor cr_phone
    is
    select Office_PHONE_ID,IS_PHONE_PRIMARY
    from Office_PHONE
    where Office_ID = p_ID
    order by SEQ_NUMBER;
    begin
    wPhID :=NULL;
    wPhID1:=NULL;
    for wp in cr_phone
    loop
    if wPhID is NULL
    then wPhID1:=wp.Office_PHONE_ID;
    end if;
    if wp.IS_PHONE_PRIMARY = 'Y'
    then
    wPhID:=wp.Office_PHONE_ID;
    Exit;
    end if;
    end loop;
    if wPhID is NULL
    then wPhID:=wPhID1;
    end if;
    return(wPhID);
    end OfficeIDMainPhoneID;
```

SQL Server attempt:

```
create function OfficeIDMainPhoneID(@p_ID t_OfficeID)
returns t_OfficePhoneID
as
begin
    declare @wPhID  t_OfficePhoneID;
    declare @wPhID1 t_OfficePhoneID;
  declare cr_phone cursor local
  for
    select Office_PHONE_ID,IS_PHONE_PRIMARY
    from Office_PHONE
    where Office_ID = @p_ID
    order by SEQ_NUMBER;

    set @wPhID =NULL;
    set @wPhID1=NULL;
    declare wp cursor for cr_phone
    open wp;
    fetch wp into;
    while @@fetch_status=0
    begin
      if @wPhID is NULL
      begin set @wPhID1=wp.Office_PHONE_ID;
      end 
      if wp.IS_PHONE_PRIMARY = 'Y'
      begin
        set @wPhID=wp.Office_PHONE_ID;
        Exit;
      end 
    fetch wp into;
    end;
    close wp;
    deallocate wp;
    if @wPhID is NULL
    begin set @wPhID=@wPhID1;
  end 
  return(@wPhID);
  end ;
```

Comment: Thank you scsimon for the formating help !!

Comment: It's late here and I've had my share of beers, but this function looks way too complicated for the little it does - maybe you do not need it at all. If you do, it can be done much shorter.

Comment: While I totally agree with you Erich, I am not a master at this language at this point to be able to rewrite it.  Slowly I am learning both the language and this very long massive script is very poorly written.  So I hope to peel this onion back and simplify the code.  Still one step at a time, right?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question about the functions as written

If you just want to fix the cursor so it works, one problem is the two "fetch wp into;" statements. You are saying "fetch the data and put it into" and then not giving it anything to put it into.  Declare a couple of variables, put the data into them, then later use the variables, not the code. You need one variable per item returned in your cursor definition, so one each for Office_PHONE_ID and IS_PHONE_PRIMARY.

Also, you are trying to declare variables (and the function) as t_OfficePhoneID, I suspect that should be something like INT OR BIGINT instead (whatever the table definition for the column is).

```
Declare @OP_ID INT, @ISPRIMARY CHAR(1) --Or whatever the column is
```

later (in two locations),

```
fetch wp into (@OP_ID, @ISPRIMARY);
```

then use @OP_ID instead of wp.Office_PHONE_ID, and so on.

HOWEVER, I would throw away all the code in the function after declaring @wPhID, and do something else. Cursors suck if you can get what you want with a simple set based request. If you work your way through the oracle code, it is doing the following:
Get the id of the first phone number marked primary (in sequence order). If it didn't find one of those, just get the id of the first non-primary phone number in sequence order. You can do that with the following

```
set @wPhID = select TOP 1 Office_PHONE_ID
from Office_PHONE
where Office_ID = @p_ID
order by CASE WHEN IS_PHONE_PRIMARY = 'Y' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, SEQ_NUMBER;
```

Return @wPhID and you're done.

I used "CASE WHEN IS_PHONE_PRIMARY = 'Y' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END" in the order by because I don't know what other values are possible, so this will always work. If you know the only possible values are 'Y' and 'N', you could use something like the following instead

```
order by IS_PHONE_PRIMARY DESC, SEQ_NUMBER;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this DancingFool.  Sorry for the late reply... I didn't see that there was a response and now I do.  I caught a couple of things you advised me to watch out for and do, but really appreciate your explanation of what's going on in general.   As stated I am not an Oracle guy, but looking through other functions and queries whoever worked on this stuff was sloppy, redundant, or both a lot of the time.  Thanks Again!